# Remove non-English observations from dataframe

Tags: r, text, twitter, text-mining

I have a dataframe with Twitter data. I have cleaned the Tweet text and added it as a vector, `clean_text`, but there are numerous observations in a non-English language that affect my text analysis. How do I remove all observations in the dataframe that are not written in English?

---

Here is a reproducible sample of my dataframe, `BrexitTweets`.

```
structure(list(`Tweet ID` = c(746280472381107968, 746280472355929984, 
746280472154603008, 746280472129342976, 746280472083332992, 746280472037170944, 
746280471831645952, 746280471814888960, 746280471777185024, 746280471756180992, 
746280471743565056, 746280471705844992, 746280471680658944, 746280471676488960, 
746280471676455936, 746280471617757056, 746280471613570944, 746280471600992000, 
746280471525469952, 746280471403847040), Time = c("24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04"), `Tweet Type` = c("Tweet", "Retweet", 
"Retweet", "Retweet", "Retweet", "Retweet", "Tweet", "Retweet", 
"Tweet", "Retweet", "Tweet", "Tweet", "Retweet", "Tweet", "Retweet", 
"Retweet", "Retweet", "Tweet", "Retweet", "Retweet"), `Retweeted By` = c(NA, 
"misyed_", "Skuys", "priyadarshibbc", "Amaranta_2012", "ECCA_Nordic", 
NA, "Dat_Sync", NA, "SirDeGuz", NA, NA, "RoGreca_", NA, "30SecondsToMoon", 
"StuartGray", "DataDebate", NA, "alek_dev", "addi_GrBj"), `Number of Retweets` = c(0, 
251, 4, 14, 2, 39, 0, 6462, 0, 1391, 0, 0, 31595, 0, 27, 15, 
35, 0, 6462, 20521), `Number of Followers` = c(6079, 434717, 
16036, 345319, 4566, 3223810, 109145, 560, 78, 1957, 766, 1299, 
2155087, 235, 1925, 735, 8045, 159, 560, 128027), `Number Following` = c(2314, 
1994, 12403, 344855, 1012, 765, 333, 236, 132, 1407, 294, 1381, 
1, 338, 725, 1601, 831, 969, 236, 1606), clean_text = c("mayagoodfellow as always making sense of it all for us ive never felt less welcome in this country brexit  httpstcoiai5xa9ywv", 
"never underestimate power of stupid people in a democracy brexit", 
"gana el brexit reino unido decide abandonar la unión europea httpstco66cwudtsxu vía elmundoes", 
"uk prime minister set to resign brexit httpstco0bxbdmiswm", 
"oye junckereu que dice la ciudadanía de uk que tus tratados se los pasan por sus urnas brexit httpstcoedqfkl", 
"a quick guide to brexit and beyond after britain votes to quit eu httpstcos1xkzrumvg httpstcocniutojkt0", 
"this selfinflicted wound will be his legacy cameron falls on sword after brexit euref httpstcoegph3qonbj httpstcohbyhxodeda", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"this is a very good summary no biasspinagenda of the legal ramifications of the leave result brexit httpstcolobtyo48ng", 
"you cant make this up cornwall votes out immediately pleads to keep eu cash this was never a rehearsal httpstco", 
"brexit httpstconwutx2owcs", "brexit primer anàlisi de les conseqüencies en món de lesport httpstcon3bdrqz5cf via iusport unioesports", 
"no matter the outcome brexit polls demonstrate how quickly half of any population can be convinced to vote against itself q", 
"es ist nicht immer klug das volk entscheiden zu lassen brexit", 
"gli studenti europei verranno considerati extraeuropei e rimarranno senza assistenza sanitaria assurdo brexit", 
"i wouldnt mind so much but the result is based on a pack of lies and unaccountable promises democracy didnt win brexit pro", 
"brexit einfach erklärt httpstcou7jhlhrpim", "brexit httpstcoiive3hsj26", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"absolutely brilliant poll on brexit by yougov httpstcoepevg1moaw"
)), .Names = c("Tweet ID", "Time", "Tweet Type", "Retweeted By", 
"Number of Retweets", "Number of Followers", "Number Following", 
"clean_text"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: I think there is no quick fix for this _because_ some English words are valid in both English and other languages.  E.g. the word `stark`, off the top of my head, is both an English and a German word.

Comment: What about identifying all observations that contain a non-English character (ex. ä, å, ø, ñ, etc.) and removing those? It might not get 100% of the non-English observations but I think it would significantly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the text cat package

```
# install.packages("textcat") - install this package 
require(textcat)
require(dplyr)
data$Languages <- textcat(data$clean_text)
data <- data %>% filter(Languages == "english")
```

Comment: Looks promising. Can you please show me how to apply this directly to my dataframe? There is a reproducible sample above.

Comment: Change 'data' to the name of your data frame in all instances above and it should work seemlessly

Answer (score 0):

You may try identifying rows whose text contains non English characters using `grepl`:

```
nonmatch <- df[grepl("[^A-Za-z0-9[:punct:][:space:]]", df$text), ]
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to apply this to my data... maybe I'm not catching a typo?        `>newbrexittweets <- post_brexit1[grepl("[^[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]", df$clean_text), ]`
`>Error in df$clean_text : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`